# Migrar Microsoft SQL para Postgres

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, migrations

Preciso migrar o meu banco SQL server para Postgre-SQL, mas não tenho muita intimidade com banco de dados em si. Existe alguma ferramenta que possa auxiliar na migração? Tenho o backup do gerado do MS SQL .bak é possível converte-lo?
Grato!

Comment: Sim, é possível. O PostgreSQL tem uma Wiki completa sobre isso. Dê uma olhada: wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server_to_PostgreSQL_Migration_by_Ian_Harding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O início de uma exportação de uma base de dados para arquivos que possam ser importados no PostgreSQL é localizar e abrir no menu do SQL SERVER a ferramenta **IMPORT AND EXPORT DATA**.
Após localizar, devera abrir esta opção, na qual aparecerá uma janela de boas vindas do **DTS (DATA TRANSFORMATION SERVICES IMPORT/EXPORT WIZARD)**.
Clicando em Next passamos para o próximo nível no qual será escolher De onde iremos exportar os dados,depois destas opções ainda temos a última e mais importante, na qual será a escolha do banco de dados no qual iremos nos conectar para exportação.

Basta seguir o passo a passo deste tutorial: [**Migrando de SQL Server para PostgreSQL**](http://www.devmedia.com.br/migrando-de-sql-server-para-postgresql/3967)

Comment: Opa, @PauloRober dei uma olhada no tutorial, uma dúvida que ainda ficou, (pois esqueci de mencionar que não estou usando sistema operacional **Windows** esse precedimento só é possível se eu tiver um SQL server instalado no **WINDOWS**?

Comment: @AristótelesCoutinho agora você me pegou, mas acredito que a sistematica é a mesma pois esta função não é do Sistema Operacional e sim do banco de Dados.